# UIAlertView validation before closing

Tags: objective-c, ios, uialertview

Is there a way to add a validation check for textfield in a UIAlertView before closing the alert? E.g. check user credentials like username and password, and if its incorrect, update the text in the UIAlertView that credentials are incorrect. Only dismiss the UIAlertView when the validation check passes.

thanks!

Comment: You should avoid text entry in `UIAlertView`s anyway. That functionality is subject to change and your application may be rejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd want to subclass [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIActionSheet) to provide this behavior.  It doesn't look to me like it's possible to validate text entry and keep the UIAlertView open.

Alternatively, you could validate the text entered and reshow the UIAlertView if the password entered isn't correct.

Comment: Is it possible to override button click handler in the subclass, and redraw the alert?

Comment: What did you do to solve this problem? I have something very similar and can't quite figure it out.